# Notification to my website in realtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, web, notifications

I just want to have an idea on how to make a notification in my website without refreshing the web page. For example someone is post a comment in my wall like in facebook. I want it to notify me even if I'm not refreshing my page.

I'm thinking the idea like showing running time in a website. But I think I will retrieve some data from database every minute and it might cause a lot of traffic in network..

Please help me to have an idea on this. I would appreciate it if you can give me an idea or advice.

Thank you so much..

Comment: Look into ajax and partial page rendering... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386573%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and that ajax panel would typically be updated by a web service for which web api is a good option http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829332/notify-client-from-server

Answer (score 4):

The way I do this is by using Javascript & AJAX on the page

something like this

```
<script>
function FetchNew(){

  $.get("/Comments/Fetch",function(response){
  for(var i = 0; i < response.messages.length; i++){
      $("#messagecontainer").append('<div class="message">' 
               + response.messages[i].content + '</div>');
  }
});
</script>
```

What this basically does is

1. start an AJAX get request to the URL /Comments/Fetch ($.get)
2. when a response is received (i've assumed your backend script returns a JSON object array) go through each "message" or "comment" in the array (for (var i = etc etc))
3. append the contents of each message to the div with id messagecontainer

its HTML counter-part would look like this

```
<div id="messagecontainer">
 YOUR MESSAGES APPENDED HERE
</div>
```

hope that helped

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [XSockets](http://xsockets.net/).

It can talk between JS and C#, and gives you real time notification for subscribed events.

They have some examples on the website, and even though ATM the documentation is a bit lacking, the developers are very responsive and I've got responses whenever I had an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Knockout for this purpose.

However, I'm not familiar with the subject, but here's a great blogpost about [Push Notifications](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/native-html5-push-notifications-with-asp-net-web-api-and-knockout-js/).

Comment: Okay I will try that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of solutions for c# or asp-net, but there is http://socket.io/ which is widely used also on large-scale sites. It's implemented in JavaScript and runs on NodeJS.

Comment: I thinks its nice. Ok i will try it